# How to preview uploaded image in custom module form

Tags: module, magento-1, image-upload, image-preview

I am learning Magento and trying to make a module to manage Chefs in a Restaurant. I created an upload button to upload image and it works (images save in directory, file name saved in database).

But I don't know how to have a small preview of the image next to the button when the image has been uploaded (like when uploading Catalog picture). At the moment, when I click "edit" to edit a Chef Info, the Image field look the same if I uploaded image already or not.

Here is my field:

```
 $fieldset->addField('image_url', 'image', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('tressympa_cheflist')->__('Profile Picture'),
        'required'  => false,
        'name'      => 'image_url',
    ));
```

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save image name with your complete path.

```
media/{yourfolder}/imagename.jpg
```

save in database with `yourfolder/imagename.jpg`

it will show automatically in edit form.

**OR**

you can rendered the field and show the image

```
$fieldset->addField('image_url', 'image', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('tressympa_cheflist')->__('Profile Picture'),
        'required'  => false,
        'renderer' => 'modulename/adminhtml_modulename_renderer_image',
        'name'      => 'image_url',
    ));
```

add your file    Block/Adminhtml/ModuleName/Renderer/Image.php

```
 <?php
    class NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_ModuleName_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{
       public function render(Varien_Object $row)   {
            $html = '<img id="' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . '" src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()) . '"';
            $html .= '/>';
            return $html;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Qaisar Satti, I thought the first solution must work but it didn't. I created a folder named 'chef_image' inside Media. And I saved in database and I opened database and it shows: `chef_image/hemp-lion-quiltsandart-300x200.jpg`. However, still no preview image :(

Comment: What ouput link you get for image

Comment: Sorry I am new to Magento.. But what do you mean my "output link"? How does it look like?

Comment: it mean what is your value in edit form for image?

Comment: can you add your edit script here too and your database value for image.

Comment: This is my file **local/tressympa/cheflist/block/adminhtml/chef/edit.php** `<?php
class Tressympa_Cheflist_Block_Adminhtml_Chef_Edit
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'tressympa_cheflist_adminhtml';
        $this->_controller = 'chef';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';
        $newOrEdit = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
            ? $this->__('Edit')
            : $this->__('New');
        $this->_headerText = $newOrEdit . ' ' . $this->__('Chef');
    }
}`

Comment: its column in my database named  `image_url`

Comment: my friends told me that it must work but I still don't know why it doesn't :(

Comment: What are the value of image_url that are saved in database

Comment: it is chef_image/{file_name}, for example: `chef_image/hemp-lion-quiltsandart-300x200.jpg`

Comment: did you get that value of image in edit action?

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved this when you save the image append your path before image name.

For Ex. imagename.jpeg is image name then save it is like {yourfolder}/imagename.jpg

Hope this will help you.!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you save your image in default `media` folder instead of  `media/{yourfolder}/imagename.jpg` like change image path

```
media/{yourfolder}/imagename.jpg => media/imagename.jpg
```